# excel: conditional formatting, IF THEN statement

Tags: excel-formula

I have cell A2 with date format "dd-mmm-yy" and conditional formatted to highlight yellow if more than 7 days old.  Once a date is entered into B2 I would like a formula to remove the highlight from A2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your conditional formatting rule. If B2 is blank, and, today is more than A2 + 7 then format A2. If not, do nothing.

> =AND(ISBLANK($B$2),TODAY()>$A$2+7)